# How to return multiple values in PHP?

Tags: php

The error CODE below :

```
$ejString = (str_replace(' ', '', file_get_contents('ej.txt')));
$find_tr = strpos($ejString, 'JUMLAHRP');

function find_nilai ($ejString, $find_tr){
    while ( $find_tr != false) {
        $find_tr = strpos($find_tr, 'JUMLAHRP');
        $ejString = substr($ejString, $find_tr +8);
        echo get_string_between($ejString, $start, $end);
    }
    return $find_tr;
    return $ejString;
}
// var_dump ($find_tr);
find_nilai ($ejString, $find_tr);
```

i need to run this code, i dont know how to return more than one value in php

Comment: if you want to return two values, you should return an array or object which contains those two values inside it.

Comment: You should use `!== false` because `strpos()` can return `0`, which is equal to false.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your function is mutating the parameters it is passed to. Which can sometime lead to undesirable effects. It is best to make copies of the data to work on and keep the input parameters intact. Read more about that here: https://phptherightway.com/pages/Functional-Programming.html

Answer (score 1):

A return statement terminates the execution of the function, so the return you have underneat the other will never get called. [You can see more in this documentation page](https://www.w3resource.com/php/statement/return.php)

To return more than one value, you could use an array or a hash, combine the values you need, and then return that variable. Or consider composing more than one function.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper class around as many data properties as you want, and then declare a new instance of the class, fill it with data, and return that instance.

Once it is received by the other end, it can be queried for its properties values.

```
$ejString = (str_replace(' ', '', file_get_contents('ej.txt')));
$find_tr = strpos($ejString, 'JUMLAHRP');

class myData {
    public $find_tr;
    public $ejString;
}

function find_nilai ($ejString, $find_tr){
    while ( $find_tr != false) {
        $find_tr = strpos($find_tr, 'JUMLAHRP');
        $ejString = substr($ejString, $find_tr +8);
        echo get_string_between($ejString, $start, $end);
    }
    $obj = new myData();
    $obj->find_tr = $find_tr;
    $obj->ejString = $ejString;

    return $obj;

}
// var_dump ($find_tr);
$test = find_nilai ($ejString, $find_tr);
echo $test->find_tr;
echo $test->ejString;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only need to return two elements I would suggest using an array,

```php
$ejString = (str_replace(' ', '', file_get_contents('ej.txt')));
$find_tr = strpos($ejString, 'JUMLAHRP');

function find_nilai ($ejString, $find_tr){
    while ( $find_tr != false) {
        $find_tr = strpos($find_tr, 'JUMLAHRP');
        $ejString = substr($ejString, $find_tr +8);
        echo get_string_between($ejString, $start, $end);
    }

    return array($find_tr, $ejString);
}
$result = find_nilai ($ejString, $find_tr);
var_dump($result[0]);
var_dump($result[1]);
```